# OnDraw method on view class not being called

Tags: java, android

I'm making a chess app in android studio and came across this problem. I have a custom view "square" that I'm creating multiple instances of inside a loop and inserting them into the layout by calling layout.addView(squareClass). However, when doing this I'm expecting that the views method onDraw is going to get called so I can draw the squares on the board but that is not the case.
This is the code for creating all my squares in MainActivity.java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Board board = new Board();
    }

    public class Board {
        int WIDTH = 8;
        Square[][] squares = new Square[WIDTH][WIDTH];

        public Board(){
            LinearLayout boardLayout = findViewById(R.id.board);
            //int width  = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            //int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

            for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++){
                File file = File.values()[i];
                for(int rank = 1; rank <= WIDTH; rank++){
                    Square square = new Square(MainActivity.this, file, rank);
                    boardLayout.addView(square);
                    squares[i][rank-1] = square;
                    square.update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the square class:

```java
public class Square extends View{
    Color color;
    File file;
    Integer rank;
    Paint paint;
    Rect rect;

    public Square(Context context){ super(context); }

    public Square(Context context, File file, Integer rank){
        super(context);
        System.out.println("TESTING:   " + file.toString() + " " + rank);
        this.file = file;
        this.rank = rank;
        if(1+file.ordinal() % 2 == 0){
            color = rank % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.black;
        } else {
            color = rank % 2 == 0 ? Color.black : Color.white;
        }
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color == Color.black ? android.graphics.Color.BLACK : android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
        rect = new Rect();
    }

    public void update() {
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int screenWidth = getWidth();
        int x1 = screenWidth/8*file.ordinal();
        int x2 = screenWidth/8*(file.ordinal()+1);
        int y1 = screenWidth/8*(rank-1);
        int y2 = screenWidth/8*rank;
        canvas.drawRect(x1,y1,x2,y2,paint);
        System.out.println("IM CALLED");
    }
}
```

The system log that says "IM CALLED" is only called once while the system log that says "TESTING " and some info about the class is called in each instance of a square. Appreciate any help given!

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `invalidate();` in your View class after the end of your loop. Calling `invalidate();` will triggers onDraw and update your View to display it on the UI. You can achieve this by creating an update method in your View class, like this:

```
public class Square extends View {
...
    public void update() {
        invalidate();
    }
...
}
```

I your Activity, you call `square.update();` at the end of your loop, as I mentioned above.

Comment: This did not work, "im called" is still only getting called once and I can only see on square in my app.

Comment: Could you please provide the updated code in your Board class?

Comment: Thanks, I will be looking into it. Next time, please use websites like pastebin to put your code, as editing your original question won't help future users who come across the same problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that in the future!